# “Unique” doesn't have a unique meaning

Tags: logic, terminology, definition, education

When using words like “unique” and “any”, particularly in technical communication, I sometimes find myself deliberating over which definition and tenor is the most natural, or which alternative phrasing might be clearer even if less succinct or accessible.

Does “**Every boy has a unique shirt**” mean that

- no two boys have the same shirt,

or does it mean that

- no two shirts belong to the same boy?

I suppose the former; if so, then does the latter mean “**Every shirt belongs to a unique boy**”?

Comment: I would interpret the sentence in the second way. But in natural language it can mean either one.

Comment: It could as well mean "Every boy has at least one shirt that no other boy has". That's really the difference between mathematical/logic formulations and everyday speech. The latter is often ambiguous!

Comment: If I meant that no shirt belongs to two boys, I would say "every boy has a *distinct* shirt".

Comment: Or: There exists a unique shirt, and every boy has it …

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Hehe. Then you must mean that the shirt's *design* is unique,   not that there's only a single shirt or single ownership.

Comment: Closely related: [Confusion on understanding a proposition on equivalence classes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306604/confusion-on-understanding-a-proposition-on-equivalence-classes)

Comment: @MJD Just to point out that touching on the formalisations of "at most one", "[exactly one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4319110/21813)" and "at least one" in a fuller discussion (about the ambiguity of “unique”) than in my self-Answer would require more than just getting quantifier order correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to MJD's, Dario's and Cheerful Parsnip's comments and answers:

1. “**Every $A$ has a unique $B$**” has multiple interpretations:
    $(1)$ Each $A$ has at least one $B$ that no other $A$ has;
    $(2)$ Each $A$ has exactly one $B,$ which no other $A$ has;
    $(3)$ Each $A$ has exactly one $B.$
2. To illustrate these interpretations, read each of the following
   lines (their labels correspond to the interpretation numbers
   above) as “**Every bin has a unique score**” (bins are separated
   by indentation and scores by commas):
   \begin{gather}6,4\quad 7,5\quad 8,0\quad 9,0\quad \tag{1}\\ 6\quad\quad 7\quad\quad 8\quad\quad 9\quad\quad \tag{1,2,3}\\
   7\quad\quad 7\quad\quad 7\quad\quad 7\quad\quad \tag{3}\end{gather}
3. Interpretation $(1)$ corresponds to the most common definition of ‘unique’ as *having no duplicate*.

   Interpretation $(2)$ corresponds more accurately to “Each $A$ has a **distinct** $B$”.

   Interpretation $(3)$ corresponds to the common technical usage of ‘unique’ to connote *having no alternative possibility*.
4. All in all, **due to its ambiguity *and* frequent conflation with the word ‘*distinct*’, I would just avoid using the word ‘*unique*’ in the above sense**.

   (On the other hand, “uniquely determined” isn't ambiguous and corresponds squarely to interpretation $(3)\,).$

---

It turns out that all the four statements in the Question have different meanings!

- $(S_1)\quad$ “Every boy has a unique shirt.”
- $(S_2)\quad$ “Every shirt belongs to a unique boy.”
- $(S_3)\quad$ “No two boys have the same shirt.”

  Every shirt belongs to at most one boy. $$∀s,b_1,b_2\;\Big(P(s,b_1)∧P(s,b_2)\implies b_1=b_2\Big).$$
- $(S_4)\quad$ “No two shirts belong to the same boy.”

  Every boy has at most one shirt. $$∀b,s_1,s_2\;\Big(P(s_1,b)∧P(s_2,b)\implies s_1=s_2\Big).$$

$(S_1)$ and $(S_2)$ are discussed in the previous section, and are clearly inequivalent;

since $(S_3)$ and $(S_4)$ each allows some boy to own no shirt, neither is equivalent to $(S_1);$

since $(S_3)$ and $(S_4)$ each allows some shirt to have no owner, neither is equivalent to $(S_2);$

$(S_3)$ and $(S_4)$ are clearly inequivalent.

Comment: I disagree--technical communication is exactly the context where you *can* use "unique".  In mathematical writing, "Every A has a unique B" pretty much always means (1).  It is only in a non-technical context (dealing with an audience who is not familiar with mathematical language) that the ambiguity arises.

Comment: @EricWofsey While "she has a unique talent" is always unambiguous, I prefer to describe $[7\quad7\quad7\quad7]$ with "every bin has $\require{cancel}\cancel{\text{a unique}}$ exactly one$\,$ score" in both non-technical _and_ technical contexts.

Comment: Please note that due to my Answer having been revised, the "(1)" in Eric's comment now actually refers to Interpretation (3) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Closely approximating the English is the following logical formula $$\forall b \exists!s P(s,b)$$ where $b$ is a boy and $s$ is a shirt, and $P(s,b)$ means that s belongs to b. This means that for each boy there is one and only one shirt that belongs to him. If you want to say that no shirt belongs to two boys you would say $$\forall s\exists! b P(s,b),$$ and the natural language approximation would be "Every shirt belongs to a unique boy."

Comment: By the way this last sentence is the same as yours, but we are taking them to mean different things.

Comment: In natural language, how would you use the word "unique" to write that "Every linear transformation has exactly one matrix representation?" (A matrix may represent an infinite number of linear transformations, but leave this information or its implications out.)

Comment: You might say something like "Every linear transformation is represented by a unique matrix." (Even though this is false. :))

Comment: Yes, my first instinct was to write that too. ("Every LT, with respect to chosen bases in the domain and codomain, has a unique matrix representation.") Then I wavered and decided that the reader would as well interpret that to mean no two LT (with respect to the same bases) share the same representation, which is patently false!

Comment: 1. Actually, “no shirt belongs to two boys” (i.e., “no two boys share the same shirt”) means that every shirt belongs to *at most* one boy instead of that every shirt belongs to *exactly* one boy; as such, its formalisation is $$∀s\;∃b_1\;∀b_2\;\big(P(s,b_2){\implies}b_2{=}b_1\Big)$$ ([equivalently](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#~6s~6x~6y(Psx~1Psy~5y=x)~5~6s~7x~7y(Psy~5y=x)): $∀s,b_1,b_2\;\big(P(s,b_1)∧P(s,b_2){\implies}b_2{=}b_1\Big)$) instead of $$\forall s\exists! b P(s,b).$$ 2. Summarising your Answer: your preferred interpretation of  ‘unique’ is  ‘exactly one’.