# Does unique mean "at most one" or "exactly one"?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

This is a bit of a soft question, but what does or should "unique" mean? Does it mean "at most one" or "exactly one"? I have seen different textbooks use different conventions on this matter.

Comment: Usually unique means exactly one

Comment: Context matters.  One could say, e.g., "if there is a solution then it is unique" which clearly does not imply existence.

Comment: @lulu Your statement doesn't imply existence but uniqueness means exactly one. In fact, I would translate your statement as, if there is a solution then there is exactly one.

Comment: An adjective applies to a noun. So just to use the word "unique" you must already be in a context that assumes existence (even if it is a small local context as in lulu's example). My two cents.

Comment: @JohnDouma  My point was that use of the word "unique" does not imply existence.  Indeed, the most typical use of the term would probably be something like "there exists a unique solution"   which at least suggests that existence is something which must additionally be specified.

Comment: This is an English question because, unlike continuous say, unique is not a mathematical term. It is used by mathematicians but doesn't have a rigorous definition special to mathematics.

Comment: I agree with John Douma that this isn't really a mathematics question, but rather a question about English.  That being said, **context matters**.  You will often see the phrase "there exists a unique solution"---in this case, "unique" does not imply existence, so the adjective means that there is *at most* one solution, while the phrase "there exists" gives us *at least* one solution.  As another data point, uniqueness of solutions to PDEs is often shown before existence is even considered---in this context, "unique" again means "at most one".

Comment: I agree with John Douma and Xander Henderson. Regarding differential equations theory (ordinary and partial), I recall quite well that one *very often* (in textbooks, class, etc.) talks about the two halves of a result about solutions—[existence and uniqueness](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22differential+equation%22+%22existence+and+uniqueness%22), with existence almost always being the more difficult half.

Comment: I think this is on-topic as a question about math terminology, not general English.  The words "uniqueness" and "existence" are used in a specific way in math.

Comment: There is no unique answer since it depends on context and convention. As you wrote, "I have seen different textbooks use different conventions on this matter".

Comment: @Somos, it seems you are right, since there are two posted answers. There exists an answer, but there does not exist a unique answer, to what unique means  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between "at most one" and "exactly one" is small but important. As it turns out, "exactly one" implies that there is "at most one", but not the other way around. This makes either acceptable as a stand-in for unique, depending on the context.

"at most one x" means that if you have two things, and both of them are x, they must actually be identical. BUT, there is nothing in "at most one" that guarantees there exists an x. Example: "there is at most one prime divisible by 4" is true, even though there is no such prime.

"exactly one x" guarantees that there exists an x and that there is at most one of these x. Thus, it is a stronger statement than "at most one". So, "there is exactly one prime divisible by 4" is false, since there are no such primes.

Importantly, both of these statements capture the idea behind uniqueness. Often, talk about unique objects presupposes that the object in question exists and so "exactly one" works fine.

But, one occasionally gets statements like "unique, if it exists" which correspond to "at most one".

Answer (score 2):

#### It depends how you define "unique".

*Uniqueness existential quantification* is the concept that there exists one and only one solution or element to satisfy some kind of conditions. The example given on Wiki is that there exists exactly one number n in the natural numbers such that n-2=4; namely, that being n = 6. Thus, it generates a singleton, but not the null set.

This is a more constrained definition of uniqueness than the possibility of there being 0 solutions. In linear algebra, matrices and differential equations often have what is treated as three different types of solutions:

- one (1) unique solution
- no solution (0)
- infinitely many

The result is based on how the matrix / differential is constructed and constrained. In the instance in which one has 0 solutions, there could be close approximations, but those are still not direct solutions. The question then becomes whether or not no solutions is a solution or just a statement of fact. By contrast, if the differential isn't constrained enough, then there could be infinitely many solutions, and thus there is no uniqueness in the solution at all.

Limits are also treated in an interesting way in that sometimes the limit simply isn't computable due to asymptotic divergence, etc., and thus we say that the solution is nonexistent or "the limit does not exist" (DNE), meaning that it doesn't converge to a single solution, discrete and finite, but rather goes off into infinity. That is the answer, but do we call it a solution, or a lack thereof?

Further, there's so-named "essentially unique" where objects are unique solutions only due to the fact that all other solutions are identical through equivalence relations. This is the basis for the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

I'm sure there are more advanced examples in analysis, number theory, combinatorics, and topology that I have no idea what they mean, including things being equivalent up to a certain isomorphism, but I think that these examples are reasonably expressive in the types of uniqueness that can exist in mathematical discourse.

Answer (score 1):

1. > Does unique mean "at most one" or "exactly one"?

   The word “unique” per se never just means at most one.

   While the *entire phrasing* “a unique solution, if it exists” means at
   most one (i.e., either $0$ or $1$ solution, depending on whether
   it exists), the word “unique” itself in this context simply means
   **exactly one**. (After all, having no solution entails having no unique solution.)
2. > Does unique mean "at most one" or "exactly one"?

   In (points #3 and #4, interpretation $(3)$ of) my self-answer to
   [“Unique” doesn't have a unique
   meaning](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3926202/21813), I gathered
   that mathematicians regularly use “unique” to mean **exactly one**.
   However, if this definition is taken literally, then “every column
   has a unique digit” is true of both the second and *third* rows:
   \begin{gather}6,4\quad 7,5\quad 8,0\quad 9,0\quad \\ 6\quad\quad
   7\quad\quad 8\quad\quad 9\quad\quad \\ 7\quad\quad 7\quad\quad
   7\quad\quad 7\quad\quad \end{gather} In view of this, the second row
   is more clearly described as “every column has a **distinct** digit”
   (i.e., each row has exactly one digit, which no other row has),
   while the third row directly as “every column has **exactly one**
   digit”.

   (To be clear: I'm pointing out that it sounds weird to describe
   every column of row three as having a unique digit.)
3. For completeness, I added the first row to illustrate a third (and
   typical) usage of “unique” in common parlance, one that connotes
   neither **exactly one** nor **at most one**: here, “every column has
   a unique digit” actually means that each row has **at least one**
   digit that no other row has.

Comment: Your "common parlance" is just sloppy English. If you must use the word "unique" in that context, then you should say "every column contains a digit that is unique to that column". It's much clearer to say "every column contains a digit that occurs in no other column". Serious misuses of the word "unique" are widespread in computing and engineering, so we should set a good example in Mathematics.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment, which supports my Answer and its point that *both* the technical and non-technical usages of "unique" *can* be ambiguous (but not always: "uniquely determined" is clear), due to definitional issues. My row-2 example can be interpreted three ways: by literally/faithfully applying Dictionary.com's defn of "unique" as "existing as the sole example", by applying the defn "a unique := exactly one", or by applying the defn "unique := distinct"; in each case, a more thoughtful construction or phrase choice (our alternative suggestions) disambiguates the intended meaning.