# How do we tell whether ‘some’ means Exactly one or At least one?

Tags: logic, terminology, predicate-logic, logic-translation

> A natural number $n$ is even if it has the form $n = 2k$ for some $k$ $\in$ $\mathbb N.$

I'm confused by the usage of 'some' in this definition. Isn't "exactly one" more suitable for this definition? I mean, when you choose one value of $n,$ just one value of $k$ matches that.

How do we know whether 'some' means **at least one** or **just one**? Depending on the context?

Anyway, why do we say "some", rather than "all" or "any", to mean at least one? I mean, it does sound like they all suggest “at least one”.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137463/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-li-why-do-we-say-some-rather-than-all-or-a).

Comment: This is not a question of mathematics but rather English.

Comment: Well, we definitely couldn't use _all_.

Comment: Thank you so much @ryang, and I found some useful information here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification, it says "It does not matter that "n·n = 25" is only true for a single natural number, 5; even the existence of a single solution is enough to prove this existential quantification as being true. "

Comment: @ZhenLin: this question is not about mathematics *per se* I would say that it *is* a mathematical question:  OP is trying to understand a *mathematical statement* where the meaning of the natural language used in the statement is unclear to OP.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34984/21813) is my perspective on why the OP's question is a natural (thus common) one for someone unschooled in [Mathematical English](https://abstractmath.org/MM/MMMathEnglish.htm#:%7E:text=Mathematical%20English%20is%20a%20special,English%20is%20a%20foreign%20language.).

Comment: @ZhenLin I've added the *terminology* tag.

Comment: Since $n\mapsto2k$ is a bijection from $\Bbb N\to2\Bbb N$, given that the definition stipulates a single natural number $n$, there must always be only a single natural number $k$, so there is no ambiguity in the usage in your example. Nevertheless, I think *some* is just quicker and easier than "not none".

Comment: This question is very clearly not a duplicate of the suggested question since neither that question nor any of its answers say anything at all about the meaning of "some".  I would not be surprised if this is a duplicate of some other question but voters should pay attention to what questions actually say and not just assume two questions that are kind of similar are the same.

Comment: [I vehemently agree with](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34973#comment164075_34973) @EricWofsey's comment "**voters should pay attention to what Questions actually say, and not assume two Questions that are kind of similar are the same.**"  $\quad$ A a close-reviewer has suggested [Does unique mean "at most one" or "exactly one"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4209294) as duplicate target; I have previously Answered, in detail, both Questions, and know them inside out: they are assuredly not duplicates, and neither are the two sets of Answers REMOTELY interchangeable.

Comment: For the record, the close-reviewer referred to in my previous comment has conceded (in a subsequently comment that accidentally got deleted while we were cleaning up our conversation) that they had been remiss in suggesting that duplicate target.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do we know whether 'some' means **at least one** or **just one**?

“**For some** $k,\, P(k)$ is true”, “**there exists at least one** $k$ such that $P(k)$ is true” and “**there exists one** $k$ such that $P(k)$ is true” all have the same meaning.

This remains the case even when we separately deduce that only/exactly/just one value of $k$ actually satisfies $P(k),$ as in this example:

> > A natural number $n$ is even if it has the form $n = 2k$ for some $k$ $\in$ $\mathbb N$
>
> when you choose one value of $n,$ just one value of $k$ matches that.

yes.

> isn't "exactly one" more suitable for this definition?

In formulating the above **definition**, “for exactly one $k$” and the less specific “for at least one $k$” are equally logical and correct. But there is a subtle but important difference (EDIT: thanks, Surb, for contributing the following point):

1. if the definition of $n$ being even is the *existence of exactly one* $k$ such that $n=2k+1,$ then, to verify that $17$ is even, we must find $k=8$ AND show that there is no other $k$ satisfying the property;
2. whereas if the definition of $n$ being even is the *existence of (at least one)* $k$ such that $n=2k+1,$ then, to verify that $17$ is even, we JUST need to find $k=8.$

However, when using a **theorem**, the former formulation is stronger and more convenient: if $n$ is even, then we know that there exists *exactly* (rather than merely *at least*) one $k$ such that $n=2k+1.$

> Depending on the context?

We often default to “at least one” because it is a direct translation of the commonly-used quantifier $\text‘\exists\text’.$ If more precision is necessary (and justifiable),we can just say, for example, “exactly one” or “at least two” or “three”, instead of “some”.

> Why do we say "some", rather than "all" or "any", to mean at least one? I mean, it does sound like they all suggest “at least one”.

All three indeed imply “at least one”—but only “some” is *equivalent* to “at least one”.

After all, why should **some** (i.e., at least one) value of $k$ satisfying $P(k)$ imply that **all** values of $k$ satisfy $P(k)\,??$

And, letting $k\in\mathbb R,$ why should $(k-3)(k-7)=0$ and $14=2k$ being true for $k=7$ (**some** value of $k$) imply that they are true for **every** and **any** value of $k,$ including $13\,?$

Comment: On a related note: while "for any $x$" clearly means "for each $x$", [the phrase "if any $x$" strongly suggests "if some $x$" rather than "if each $x$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4646789/21813).